# AngularJS Nested ng-repeat that connects with the ID from two JSON arrays

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to find the best way to connect two arrays together in i guess would be the nested ng-repeat. This is the data i have available (very short example);

```
GameGenre Table
ID    |    Genre
1     |    Action
2     |    First Person Shooter
3     |    Adventure

Game Table
ID    |    IDGenre   |  Name
1     |    1         |  SpiderMan
2     |    1         |  Batman
3     |    2         |  Wolfenstein
4     |    3         |  Just Cause
5     |    3         |  Tomb Raider
6     |    3         |  Indiana jones
```

So i am looking for the best way (a way / fasted way) to combine there two array together so i get this out

```
IDGameGenre 1 Holds: GAMEID1 and GameID2
IDGameGenre 2 Holds: GameID3
IDGameGenre 3 Holds: GameID4, GameID5, GAMEID6
```

this is what i come up with so far, i first consume the two arrays:

In the controller:

```
 $http({
     method: 'Get',
     url: http://URL/api/GameGenre/All"
 })
     .success(function (data) {
          $scope.GameGenre= data;
     });

 $http({
     method: 'Get',
     url: http://URL/api/Game/All"
 })
     .success(function (data) {
          $scope.Game= data;
     });

 $scope.getTheGame = function(ID) {
     return Game.get({IDGenre: ID});
 };
```

In the HTML

```
<div class="listing" ng-repeat="Genre in GameGenre" ng-init='getTheGame(Genre.ID)'>
       <div class="Game" ng-repeat="Game in getTheGame"></div>
</div>
```

but i can't seem to get this two work, how would i be able to first consume the two arrays, add them both to a scope and then get the information sorted.

Comment: why dont you do add that functionality on your backend? in your GameGenre class, add a list of games and to that list add all the games which are against this Genre. With this approach, you wont have to make two separate calls to the backend either

Comment: i can't unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your `$http` requests are asynchronous. You need to either chain them, or resolve synchronously, which can be done with `$q.all()`. Then, once resolved and populated into arrays, you can manipulate them and create a new array for your table. I found 2 for loops to be the simplest way of doing it (*good luck making it shorter with* `.map`/`.reduce`/etc.).

Here is a static example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q) {
  /*
  var GGpromise = $http(...).then(function (res) {
    return res.data;
  });
  var Gpromise = $http(...).then(function (res) {
    return res.data;
  });
    
  $q.all([GGpromise, Gpromise]).then(function(res){
    var GG = res...;
    var G = res...;
  }).finally(function(){
    // main code here:
    // ...
  })
  */
  
  var GG = [
    {"ID":1,"Genre":"Action"},
    {"ID":2,"Genre":"First Person Shooter"},
    {"ID":3,"Genre":"Adventure"}
  ];
  var G = [
    {"ID":1,"IDGenre":1,"Name":"Spider Man"},
    {"ID":2,"IDGenre":1,"Name":"Batman"},
    {"ID":3,"IDGenre":2,"Name":"Wolfenstein"},
    {"ID":4,"IDGenre":3,"Name":"Just Cause"},
    {"ID":5,"IDGenre":3,"Name":"Tomb Raider"},
    {"ID":6,"IDGenre":3,"Name":"Indiana Jones"}
  ];

  $scope.games = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < GG.length; i++) {
    var temp = {};
    temp.IDGameGenre = GG[i].ID;
    temp.Holds = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < G.length; j++) {
      if (GG[i].ID == G[j].IDGenre) {
        temp.Holds.push(G[j].ID);
      }
    }
    $scope.games.push(temp);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <pre>{{games | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

or you can try something like:-

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="Genre in GameGenre">{{ Genre.Name }}</li>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="Game in GameArray" ng-if="Game.GenreId == Genre.Id">{{ Game.Name }}</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: I understand i works, however it will illiterate over all options, now imagine my games list is about 50.000 rows. So i don't think this is the best option performance wise.

Comment: However it's a very simple solution and what would be the difference if i would illiterate over all in the controller like in the example of Aleksey? Anyone else any ideas on performance?

Comment: @EwaldBos you would need to reduce the number of **watchers** with one-time data-binding. Change `ng-repeat="x in array"` syntax to `ng-repeat="x in ::array"`, as well as `{{x}}` to `{{::x}}`. You can also limit the number of elements shown with a filter: `ng-repeat="... | limitTo : 100 : 0"` (_show 100 starting from 0_, which can be dynamic). Note that ngRepeat creates an inner scope for each (!) element in the array

Comment: @EwaldBos if it is possible for one genre to have 50,000 games against it and lets say you have 10 genres, thats a total of 500,000 games so its pretty obvious that you cant fit all that data in one page then why are you making a call to get all that data if you cant fit it in one page? Only get data from your backend which is required to you on your current page.

Comment: @EwaldBos I would suggest you to reconsider your design, for example render a list Genres and upon clicking one Genre from the list, go to a separate page and on the new page make a call to your backend, something like 'GetGamesByGenreId'

Comment: @Fakhar, that would unfortunately not be possible.